# Menus don't overlay my OpenGL canvas after I open another frame on Mac only

Tags: opengl, menu, jogl

I have an opengl canvas and lightweight menus set to false, and everything works fine.  Then I open up a second frame from the first that has some 2D drawing etc.  The menus over the openGL canvas in the first frame no longer draw where they overlap the canvas.  This only happens on my mac, not on linux or windows.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that if you use the UIManager to set the look and feel, it must do something to the previous setting that turned off the lightweight menus (required for JOGL).